# GridView items containing a single image does not match the height of the image even though it's set to wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gridview

I have the following GridView:

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:numColumns="3" />
```

Which I populate with this type of items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I set the image in the adapter by setting a bitmap. The images get the appropriate size for a GridView with 3 columns, but the items are way too high. This means that there is a lot of empty space above and below every image. How can I remove that space so the items have the same height as the images?

Here's an illustration of how it is right now:
[image]

Here's how it should be:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in xml,

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
```